# Finite State Machine and Robotics

Tags: state-machines

I have been wondering if I have for example to calculate one sum and a multiplication, I would have two different states, and if so, how would my truth table be, for example if I have a register **tot** to store the distance, and it's given by:

$$D = L\cdot K + f$$

For an arbitrary function, I would like to know if I would have to include one state for calculating the product $$LK$$

and another to solve the sum with f.
Any explanation would be great.

Comment: This depends entirely on what your datapath looks like. You might not need a state machine at all.

Comment: I think it's very necessary indeed.

Comment: Depends on your constraints on time, area, and budget. And only you know those so don't expect much of an answer to the question as it is. In TTL for example you'd use the adder for multiplication to save hardware, and take N cycles for multiplication then 1 cycle for addition. Or, you can do it purely combinational with no state machine or registers at all; that uses more hardware.

Comment: But, when I have a finite state machine, I need one state for sum, another for multiplying and so on, right?

Comment: No. First decide what matters. What latency and throughput you need and your hardware budget.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that way, like it's done in software: first you multiply, then you sum. Or you could to all at the same time, with a multiplier chained with the adder.

Of course the logic circuit would be extremely different. In *this* particular case there isn't a compelling reason to separate the two states: while are you adding the multiplier is idle, and viceversa. There could be a propagation time issue since both the circuits would need to stabilize but it's more of an implementation issue.

A more useful example would be computing

A*B+C*D

You could do this with:

- One adder and one multiplier, in one cycle you do A*B, the second C*D and in the third one the sum (or even doing the sum in the second cycle), or
- Use *two* multipliers and an adder and do everything in one cycle (timing notwithstanding)

The surface area/number of cell needed in the second case would be almost the double, but it will do the work in half of the time.

Comment: Can you explain how to implement using equations?